# Convert from .csv file to .xlsx excel file

Tags: excel, csv

Hi 
I am using an ASP.NET application and producing a report in excel page with .csv extension.   However I would like to produce it with .xlsx etension.
The code I am currently using is as follows:
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

```
    Dim sql As String
    Dim strLine As String = ""
    Dim attachment As String = "attachment; filename=PTW.csv"

    m_sBranch = ddlBranches.SelectedValue
    m_sRegion = ddlAreas.SelectedValue

    Dim cnn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=XYZ;Database=abc;Trusted_Connection=yes;") 

    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv"

    cnn.Open()

    sql = GetReportSql(m_sBranch, m_sRegion)

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, cnn)
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("PTW JOBS - EXPORTED ON " + DateTime.Now)

    For i = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1
        strLine = strLine & dr.GetName(i).ToString & ","
    Next
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strLine)

    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    Dim temp As String = ""
    While dr.Read()
        For i = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1
            temp = temp & dr.GetValue(i)
            temp = temp.Replace(",", " ")
            sb.Append(temp & ",")
            temp = ""
        Next
        sb.AppendLine()
        strLine = ""                            
    End While

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb.ToString())

End Sub
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: have a look around for a list of content headers.  there are doc types for xslx.  another option as you appear to be working with excel 2007 or greater is to have a look into openxml formats.  it's been a few months since i have worked with any open xml, but it's really simple once you get going and you will be able to produce proper excel 2007 documents.  if you weren't aware of this change an xlsx file extension to .zip and you will be able to open a zip file with all the xml component parts that make up the xslx

Answer (score 3):

Look into the OpenXML SDK:
I understand that my example doesn't convert .csv files, but it will steer you in the right direction.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854(office.14).aspx

I've used it in asp.net to create xlsx documents on the fly, streamed directly to the web client:

```
public static System.IO.MemoryStream ConvertToExcel(DataSet ds)
        {
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            using (SpreadsheetDocument package = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook, true))
            {
                package.AddWorkbookPart();
                package.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
                package.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();

                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataTable tbl = ds.Tables[0];
                    SheetData xlSheetData = new SheetData();
                    foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
                    {
                        Row xlRow = new Row();
                        foreach (DataColumn col in tbl.Columns)
                        {
                            object cellData = row[col];
                            Cell xlCell = null;
                            if (cellData != null)
                            {
                                xlCell = new Cell(new InlineString(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Text(cellData.ToString()))) { DataType = CellValues.InlineString };
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                xlCell = new Cell(new InlineString(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Text(String.Empty))) { DataType = CellValues.InlineString };
                            }
                            xlRow.Append(xlCell);
                        }
                        xlSheetData.Append(xlRow);
                    }

                    package.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet = new Worksheet(xlSheetData);
                    package.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet.Save();

                    // create the worksheet to workbook relation
                    package.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
                    package.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().AppendChild(new Sheet()
                    {
                        Id = package.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(package.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First()),

                        SheetId = 1,

                        Name = "Sheet1"

                    });

                    package.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();

                }
            }
            return stream;
        }
```

Comment: Dave, many thanks for putting me on right direction. Now, I have managed to open the document in excel sheet. However, the code doesn't display the 'Download File' pop up window with options Open/Save/Cancel before the document is displyed in excel. Any help.

Answer (score 0):

Shariful, from what I've read (not tried yet), I believe the best method is to set your HTTP Response headers as outlined [here.](http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html)

In short, the key seems to be setting the content-disposition header to "attachment".

e.g.:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<file name.ext>
```

Sorry that I haven't tested this, but in my searching for something closely related, almost every place I went suggests to use this method in order to force download dialog.